# Clear the # without reloading the page

Tags: javascript

I am loading all website's pages into the main index page, and updating URL display by splitting the href into segments and adding the segments after the main domain name with .hash function, like this:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var my_url = this.href;

var pathArray = this.href.split('/');

var newPathname = "";
for ( i = 3; i < pathArray.length; i++ ) {
  newPathname += "/";
  newPathname += pathArray[i];
}

$('body').load(my_url);
window.location.hash = newPathname;
```

This works okay, but I'm facing a little problem. When a user accesses http://www.mywebsite.com/ and then clicks, for example, on "About" link, the selected page loads, and the address bar displays:

**http://www.mywebsite.com/#/about**

But if a user starts with a different page:

**http://www.mywebsite.com/#/about**

Then after the click, the url becomes:

**http://www.mywebsite.com/#/about/#/about**

and so on, to infinity.

How can this be solved?

Perhaps there's a way to clear the hash and then display the new hash (that is, remove everything that starts with #/ and then add the new hash) – or maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `var my_url = this.href.replace(/#.*/,'')`
This will remove the `#` and anything after it.

Comment: Actually, @Kolink, even though your answer is the one I was looking for, it revealed another problem with the site. A page without the hash in the url, like this: `http://www.mywebsite.com/about` - still would do something like that: `http://www.mywebsite.com/about/#/about` - how can your snippet be modified to address that issue, too?

Comment: Hmm... there's not much that can be done about that, since that would require changing part of the path itself, forcing a reload. I see it happen on Facebook a few times, so I'm guessing there's no real solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split just the path component of the current URL, then don’t use

```
var pathArray = this.href.split('/');
```

because `href` will contain the full path including the hash.

Use

```
var pathArray = this.pathname.split('/');
```

instead.

Comment: thanks, @CBroe, this is useful. (I was doing it the hard way, by removing parts 0 -3 from the resulting array. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the hash doesn't refresh your page. At most it forces the browser to scroll top. If you want you can do:

```
window.location.hash = "";
```

to empty it (retaining the `#`) if you also remove the `#`from the href then your page will always reload.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be a way to update the content without the hash – I would owe a lot to someone who could explain to me how this is done here: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/express/

Comment: @ with jquery you can do: `$(window).unload(function( evt ) {evt.preventDefault()});`

Comment: Could you please tell me a little bit more about that, @fmsf? Where should that snippet be placed, and what does it do? Should any code actually be between the curly braces?